# How to create setup file with SQL Server in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have an `.exe` file. I tried to install it, but client computer needs a different SQL connection string. How to setup moment connection string change  and install setup?

Comment: Perhaps provide facility to enter SQL details and store in a config file to read from?

Comment: this my connection config , i install client computer . i need change connection string automatically .     Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class config
    Dim con1 As SqlConnection 'cun concation
    Dim strcon As String ' string coonction 

    Public Function getcontion() As SqlConnection
        strcon = "Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;database=st;User ID=sa;Password=123456;"
        con1 = New SqlConnection(strcon)
        Return con1
    End Function
End Class

Comment: maybe create a windows installer project and give it the ability to accept a different connection string as an input in one of the screens. Then you can write the appropriate string to the app's config file as you install it.

Comment: May be this tutorial could be useful for you: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/755380/Dynamic-Connection-String

Comment: ADyson , do you have video tutorial about  solution ?